# Opacity value in css

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make the background of a bar have the opacity of 50% and the foreground text to not have any opacity at all here is my code

html:

```
<div id="footer">
      <p>FOOTER TEXT</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#footer {opacity: 0.5;} #footer p {opacity: 1;}
```

Im not understanding why this is not work can anyone help?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "not working"?  What is the behavior that you are seeing with this?

Comment: Im trying to make it so the background of the footer has a opacity but not the text.

Comment: css is hairchic. You can't use it directive. more on this: http://acko.net/blog/shadow-dom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try won't work, 100% of 50% equals 50% !

If your background only must be transparent you can use a PNG-24 image or `rgba` value with `background-color` property.

Comment: But 200% of 50% is 100%... is 2 not a valid value? :P

Answer (score 2):

If the background is an image, then you have to use a translucent image.

If the background is a solid colour, then you can use an `rgba()` value. This works in the same way as `rgb()` with an additional value for the opacity level, but has limited browser support as it is a new feature in the CSS 3 drafts.

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
```

You can [combine `rgba()` with a background image](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/) for backwards compatibility.

```
background: url(blue_0.5_pixel.png);
background: rgba(0%, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
```

Comment: No point... I was just testing your code to make sure it works. It does. I'm a visual person. I like to see the result. Thought I'd share. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking in IE browser.
What you have defined will work in non-ie browsers.
To make it work in IE, chnge the style to:

```
#footer {opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);}
#footer p {opacity: 1;filter: alpha(opacity=100);}
```

Comment: no still not working even with that i have tested in firefox, chrome, and a webkit browser. not working in any of them